# C++ to pep/8 Assembly language help (linked data structures)

Tags: c++, assembly

For my one of my CSCI classes I have to translate this C++ program into assembly in pep/8:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node {
int data;
node* next;
};

int main() { 
node *first, *p;
int value, sum;
first = 0;
cin>>value;
while (value != -9999) {
p =first;
first = new node;
first->data = value;
first->next = p;
cin>>value;
}

for (p=first;p != 0; p = p->next) {
cout<<p->data<<' ';
}

sum = 0;
p = first;
while (p != 0) {
sum += p->data;
p = p->next;
}

cout <<"Sum: "<<sum<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Here is what I have for the assembly translation so far:

```
BR       main
data:    .EQUATE 0
next:    .EQUATE 2
;
;*********main()
first:   .EQUATE 6           ;local variables
p:       .EQUATE 4                     
value:   .EQUATE 2
sum:     .EQUATE 0

main:    SUBSP 8, i          
         LDA 0, i            ;first = 0
         STA first, s
         DECI value, s       ;cin>>value
while:   LDA value, s        ;while (value != -9999)
         CPA -9999, i
         BREQ endWh
         LDA first, s
         STA p, s            ;p=first
         LDA 4, i            ;first = new node
         CALL new
         STX first, s
         LDA value, s        ;first->data =value
         LDX data, i
         STA first, sxf
         LDA p, s            ;first->next = p
         LDX next, i
         STA first, sxf
         DECI value, s       ;cin>>value
         BR while
endWh:   LDA first, s         ;for (p=first
         STA p, s
for:     LDA p, s            ;p != 0
         CPA 0, i
         BREQ endFor
         LDX data, i         ;cout<<p->data
         DECO p, sxf
         CHARO ' ', i
         LDX next, i         ;p=p->next
         LDA p, sxf
         STA p, s
         BR for
endFor:  LDA 0, i
         STA sum, s          ;sum = 0
         LDA first, s        ;p = first
         STA p, s
while1:  LDA p, s            ;(while p != 0) 
         CPA 0, i
         BREQ endWh2
         LDX data, i          ;sum += p->data
         LDA p, sxf
         ADDA data, sxf                 
         STA sum, s        
         LDX next, i         ;p = p->next;
         LDA p, sxf
         STA p, s
         BR while1
endWh2:  LDA sum, s
         STRO msg1, d        ;"Sum = " 
         DECO sum, s         ;<<sum
         CHARO '\n', i       ;<<endl
         ADDSP 8, i
         STOP

msg1:    .ASCII "Sum: \x00"                          

;
;*******operator new
new:     LDX hpPtr, d
         ADDA hpPtr, d
         STA hpPtr, d
         RET0
hpPtr:   .ADDRSS heap
heap:    .BLOCK 1
         .END
```

I'm having trouble getting the

```
sum += p->data
```

line to work in assembly,

```
     LDX data, i          
     LDA p, sxf
     ADDA data, sxf                 
     STA sum, s
```

I think I'm having trouble with the addressing modes or something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find a lot of good info on PEP/8, so this is a bit of a shot in the dark, but since this has no other answers so far I'll give it a try:

It seems to me that you're not computing

`sum = p->data + sum`

but

`sum = p>data + some_weird_things_that's_improperly_addressed`

To me, it seems that it should be

```
 LDX data, i          
 LDA p, sxf   //load p->data into regA
 ADDA sum, s  //add sum to regA, regA now is p->data + sum               
 STA sum, s   //store regA back to sum
```